# How to position the center div at the bottom using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 3 div containers, and have used the flex css property to align the items, but in the tablet portrait mode, div 2 should come below the div1 and div3.

In portrait mode both the div1 and div3 should use the size of 50% each of parent container and the div2 should occupy the 100% of the parent container.

```css
.flexcontainer {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flexcontainer>div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #e46119;
  border: 1px solid #626262;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <div class="flex"> 1 </div>
  <div class="flex"> 2 </div>
  <div class="flex"> 3 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `flex` property to size the items, and the `order` property to adjust their position.

```css
.flexcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexcontainer > div {
  flex: 1 0 45%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #e46119;
  border: 1px solid #626262;
  margin: 3px;
}

.flex:nth-child(2) {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <div class="flex"> 1 </div>
  <div class="flex"> 2 </div>
  <div class="flex"> 3 </div>
</div>
```